# How can the data on the transaction still be used when the product has been deleted

Tags: mysql, bigdata, e-commerce, pos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr9th.png)

I have a problem regarding transaction data in the reports of products that have been sold. Constraints that occur if the product has entered the transaction / order but the product in question has been deleted.

How do I make the transaction report can still be used with the product that was deleted earlier?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to handle this possibility would be to add constraints to the tables involved which would make it not possible to delete a product row if an extant order exists which uses that product.  Here is what the table definitions for `Products` and `Order_Items` might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Items (
    order_item_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY fk_prod (product_id) REFERENCES Products (product_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Products (
    product_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

With this design in place, should someone attempt to delete a product record from the `Products` table while there exists on or more order item records referring to that product, the delete attempt would fail.

Comment: Thanks your replies @tim-biegeleisen.

Comment: one way that might be done by giving a limit when the owner tries to delete the product that is still concerned with Orders.

In this case, what if the product has been more than 1 year and the product is no longer used, seeing from the facts, the product must be removed from the database, if the product is deleted what about the transaction report about the product?

Thanks.

Comment: @luffynas You would probably need a trigger to do this.  And this could be a great topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

If a row in the `Products` table is used for two things, namely for purchasing the product and for reporting on a historical transaction, then you can never actually delete the row.

You might flag it in various ways:  "available_for_purchase", "inventory = 0", "no_longer_produced", etc.